# Why do Upstart jobs use `start on runlevel [2345]`?

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I see many Upstart jobs using a directive like the following:

`start on runlevel [2345]`

The [Upstart Cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#runlevels) provides the following list of runlevels for Debian/Ubuntu:

```
0 : System halt.
1 : Single-User mode.
2 : Graphical multi-user plus networking (DEFAULT)
3 : Same as "2", but not used.
4 : Same as "2", but not used.
5 : Same as "2", but not used.
6 : System reboot.
```

If 3, 4 and 5 are not used, why are they mentioned in so many job configurations? Are runlevels 3-5 used solely for compatibility with the [LSB PDA spec](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/runlevels.html)? Are they used for the benefit of other distributions?

Comment: My understanding is such: On each runlevel  you have a specific set of services starting; runlevels 3-5 can be customized for a specific set of services, so you could say they are for custom use. By default they are set to be the same as runlevel #2, hence the upstart jobs are defined to start at `[2345]`. It's up to sys-admin/owner of the system to alter the settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they are used for compatibility with other distributions and the [LSB PDA specifications](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/runlevels.html).  I have had multiple systems in which runlevels 3,4,5 were used, but don't ask me what they were, this was years back.

If it bothers you, it shouldn't be an issue to remove those runlevels in all the configurations, but I would recommend leaving it as is.  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I was curious so had a look at a couple of popular distros. CentOS appears to [make use of](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-sysv.html) runlevels 3 and 5.